# Angular 4 - Router.navigateByUrl ignores fragment extras

Tags: angular, angular-router

When using `@angular/router` (v4.4):

```
// navigates to 'home#abc'
router.navigate(["home"], { fragment: "abc" });

// navigates to 'home#abc'
router.navigateByUrl("/home#abc");

// navigates to 'home' and ignores fragment
router.navigateByUrl("/home", { fragment: "abc" });
```

First two examples are ok but I would have expected that the third example also navigates to `home#abc`. I checked in angular's implementation that `navigate` first calls `createUrlTree` where `extras.fragment` is appended to url, however `navigateByUrl` simply ignores the fragment.

It would be surprising if this was a bug that no-one actually has reported yet. Still, I would like to have a confirmation that this is by design and not a bug. :)

Thanks!

Comment: having the same trouble with angular 6.0.2. Did you got it to work somehow?